# Why is T-SQL ISNULL() truncating the string and COALESCE is not?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, coalesce, isnull, truncation

Given the following:

```
SELECT ISNULL('XY' + NULL, 'ABCDEFGHIJ') -- Outputs ABC (Why?)
SELECT COALESCE('XY' + NULL, 'ABCDEFGHIJ') -- Outputs ABCDEFGHIJ
```

Why are these statements returning different results?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

According to Microsoft [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx), for function:

```
ISNULL(check_expression, replacement_value)
```

`replacement_value` must be of a type that is implicitly convertible to the type of `check_expression`. Note that type for `'xy'+NULL` is `VARCHAR(3)`. Because of this your string `'ABCDEFGHIJ'` is cast to `VARCHAR(3)` and thus trimmed.

It sounds strange why it is not `VARCHAR(2)`, but this is the way it is - one character longer than `'xy'`. You can play with this **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/20987)** and see for yourself that type for `'xy'+NULL` is the same as for expression `CASE WHEN 1=2 THEN 'XYZ' ELSE NULL END`, which is `NULL` but is implicitly compatible to `VARCHAR(3)`.

It seems that for expression `'xy'+NULL` perceived length can be computed as `'xy'` string length (2) plus 1 for every `NULL` added. For example, type of `'xy'+NULL+NULL` is `VARCHAR(4)`, type for `'xy'+NULL+NULL+NULL` is `VARCHAR(5)` and so on - check out this **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/20994)**. This is extremely weird, but that is how MS SQL Server 2008 and 2012 work.

Comment: Good explanation, although I'm not convinced about the varchar(3) instead of varchar(2) - I can't find it documented anywhere.

Comment: I must increase the information here to explain more about the COALESCE behavior over the ISNULL behavior, from Microsoft [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx):
The COALESCE expression is a syntactic shortcut for the CASE expression. That is, the code COALESCE(expression1,...n) is rewritten by the query optimizer as the following CASE expression:

    CASE
       WHEN (expression1 IS NOT NULL) THEN expression1
       WHEN (expression2 IS NOT NULL) THEN expression2
...
ELSE expressionN
    END -> The case return type is given by the highest expr precedence.

Comment: This explains `COALESCE` behavior, but does not say anything why type of `'xy'+NULL` is `VARCHAR(3)`. This must have something to do with SQL Server internals.

Comment: I'm not sure if I get the proof by your sample. The 2nd query is a CASE that is a varchar(3) because of 'XYZ', not because of NULL, right? So I guess the remaining doubt is about 'X'+NULL becoming varchar(2) instead of varchar(1). So, is NULL considered as a single char in this CASE? Do I need to concern about overflows/truncation when using ISNULL concatenating strings?

Comment: Yes, NULL is adding 1 more character. This is super-strange, but here is definitive proof: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/20994

Comment: Fascinating trivia about 'AA' + NULL + NULL - I submitted a PR to MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs to document this behavior.  I do not believe I've ever seen this behavior in my 11 years working with SQL Server.

Answer (score 4):

You can check all the difference here, its very clear

MSDN : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx

MSDN Blog : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqltips/archive/2008/06/26/differences-between-isnull-and-coalesce.aspx

Comment: +1 for the blog post, I didn't noticed it in my first research. Very good resource.

Answer (score 0):

`ISNULL()` converts the replacement value to the type of the check expression. In this case, the type of the check expression is `CHAR(2)`, so converting the replacement value truncates it (are you sure you're getting `ABC` and not just `AB`?).

From the Microsoft [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx):

> `replacement_value` can be truncated if `replacement_value` is longer than `check_expression`.